# Why is Node.js simple http server app not working on server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lamp

I'm learning how to use Node.js apps in a server (**not my local machine**). In this situation, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/create-nodejs-web-server) in order to create a simple web server.

I have installed Node.js, and tested via CLI that **it works**. I can run javascript code, generate output in the CLI, etc. But I can't manage to make the an app work **via URL** using a browser.

The app folder structure I have is very simple:

```
index.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

This is the code I'm currently working with in `index.js`:

```
var http = require('http'); // 1 - Import Node.js core module

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {   // 2 - creating server

    if (req.url == '/') { //check the URL of the current request
        
            // set response header
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
        
            // set response content    
            res.write('<html><body><p>This is home Page.</p></body></html>');
            res.end();
    
        }
        else if (req.url == "/student") {
        
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write('<html><body><p>This is student Page.</p></body></html>');
            res.end();
    
        }
        else if (req.url == "/admin") {
        
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write('<html><body><p>This is admin Page.</p></body></html>');
            res.end();
    
        }
        else
            res.end('Invalid Request!');
    

});

server.listen(5000); //3 - listen for any incoming requests

console.log('Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..')
```

If I go **via CLI** to the app's folder and run the app (*node index.js*), I can see the expected console.log() output (*Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..*). But if then I go to the **URL** pointing at that folder, which I would expect to output `<html><body><p>This is home Page.</p></body></html>`, it doesn't work (see below for what I get).

I have a domain (http://example.com) with document root in the app's folder. Here's what I have tried:

- https://example.com *//browser shows the source code of index.js*
- https://example.com:5000 *//browser shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT*
- https://example.com/:5000 *//browser show 404 error*
- https://example.com/index.js *//browser shows the source code of index.js*
- https://example.com/index.js:5000 *//browser show 404 error*

None of those give the response I would expect. I don't know if this is a problem with my file structure, my server configuration... but I've been looking around and I can't figure why this basic example isn't working in my case, clearly I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
The server where I'm trying to run this app is a LAMP machine with CentOS 7.

Comment: “Jt Doesn’t Work”. Anything? .

Comment: "*I have a domain (http://example.com) with document root in the app's folder.*" - the domain doesn't really matter, apart from it pointing to your web server. But you need to tell us more about your server installation. What "document root" are you talking about? Is this is a server with software preconfigured to serve static files? That's not how you run node.js applications.

Comment: It works for me. If you are getting the source code of your `index.js` file then you are running another web server on port 80 but if you are getting the `console.log` line then then on port `5000` it should  work.

Comment: This is also not using `https` so you should use `http` and the correct urls are `example.com:5000/` not `example.com/:5000`

Comment: Which Linux You Got? .

Comment: “But if then I go to the URL pointing at that folder”.  You Have No Program At Folder-Folding. Try Basic. example.com:5000 <- Until Work. .

Comment: @Bergi thank you, I've edited my question to add server info (at the end). The document root is where the domain I'm using points to in the server, in this case the Node.js app's folder. The example that I followed calls the app via localhost from the browser, I was trying to replicate that in a "real" server by pointing a domain to that folder to call the app. If this is not the way, how can I execute a Node.js application from a browser? That'd be something great to learn for me.

Comment: @MinusFour what did you do to make it work? I've tried switching to port 80 but I get an error of course because it's already being used.

Comment: Ah, LAMP is the key here. You've got an Apache server running, which serves files from the "document root" for your domain and optionally executes PHP scripts in them. But that's not how node.js works. You should place your program code in some other folder (that is not published on the web), and then you need to start the node.js server *instead* of the apache one (or in addition to it, when using a separate port). Assuming the OS firewall doesn't prevent access to your port, visiting https://example.com:5000 should work, and https://example.com/index.js should not show anything.

Comment: @Bergi yep, it was a matter of opening the port and using http (not https). Seems like node.js server runs on top of Apache without issue. How would I go about moving the node.js app code outside the public folder? Like creating an index.html in the public one that loads the index.js from a different one?

Comment: It doesn't run on top of Apache. It runs next to it, completely independent (unless you redirect port 80 through Apache to port 5000). You can stop Apache and the node.js server will continue to work. Put the code anywhere in the filesystem, but not where it is made publicly available on the web by Apache. (And no, a html file does not load a javascript file in node.js - you might be thinking of clientside scripting, which is a completely different topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked in my server (Nginx), your code works fine.

After reading @MinusFour 's comment, I suspect that you didn't open 5000 port in your server's security groups.

Security Groups are like [image: this picture]

If that not work, you can also check your server's firewall setting.

As for your domain expression:

- https://example.com //browser shows the source code of index.js
- https://example.com:5000 //browser shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
- https://example.com/:5000 //browser show 404 error   **(incorrect)**
- https://example.com/index.js //browser shows the source code of index.js
- https://example.com/index.js:5000 //browser show 404 error **(incorrect)**

You can refer to https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329145?hl=en

---

I haven't got 50+ reputations to comment so I have to answer here.

Comment: This is the right answer! After I opened port 5000 (and used http instead of https) it works! Thank you!